# Por qué cuando envio un archivo codificado por axis a un servicio web soap aparecen caracteres raros?

Tags: java, webservice, weblogic, axis

Hola he estado tratando de resolver este problema por días y no encuentro la solución. Estoy usando axis para consumir un servicio web SOAP, cuando envió los datos con adjuntos y al debutar el axis me visualiza el contenido de mi archivo codificado con un signo de remplazado <?> por lo cual cuando envió así los datos al un servicio soap, me rechaza la petición y de devuelve un error por la mala codificación de mi archivo.

El archivo codificado por axis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de por que puede suceder esto? o que clase me estaría fallando?

La forma que envió los adjuntos es de esta manera:

```
DataHandler dth = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("mi_archivo.txt"));
_call.addAttachmentPart(dth);
```

Por cierto, uso weblogic para levantar mi aplicación war.

Comment: Podrías poner parte del WSDL del servicio que invocar.

Comment: Hola juan, lo siento es que esa parte es "confidencial" se supone que hay problemas con alguna libreria de java, pero no estoy muy familiarizado con esto